# How to scroll to last item in Kendo Tooltip?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a kendo grid with some data.
On "mouseover" event on each grid row, kendo-tooltip pops up with some information (User Comments).
The information being displayed on the kendo-tooltip keeps updating, to prevent overflow of information, I am using a vertical scroll using the following css:

```
k-tooltip-content{
overflow-y: scroll !important
}
```

My requirement here is - the scroll bar position of the kendo-tooltip to be pointing to the bottom so that the latest User Comment is visible when the kendo-tooltip pops up.

How can I achieve this functionality?
just to be clear I am refereeing to scroll bar of kendo-tooltip and not kendo-grid !!!

Comment: https://dojo.telerik.com/AZoFUlAC  -- can refer this sample example

Comment: is this the kind of thing you want? https://dojo.telerik.com/AZoFUlAC/4

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks @DavidShorthose

Answer (score 0):

This isn't *directly* an answer to your question, but wouldn't be better design to sort the rows displayed in the tooltip so that the most recent (and therefore most important) are shown first? Then scrolling is only necessary when the user needs to see older data.